# Python Scrape product variations BS4 - read from json

Tags: python, json

I'm using BS4 to scrape some product pages read the "sku", "price" and "stocks". Then I save every product on a csv row. For single products I could make it work very well, but for products with variants I'm blocked.

This is the json of a product with a variant:

```
{
   "id":434,
   "sku":"",
   "name":"Product XYZ",
   "brandName":"MyBrand",
   "definition":{
      "basePrice":40,
      "price":29,
   },
   "combinations":{
      "PD_34874":{
         "id":60883,
         "sku":"ABC456BLACK",
      },
      "PD_34885":{
         "id":60884,
         "sku":"ABC456WHITE",
      }
   },
   "stocks":{
      "WH32_34884":49,
      "WH32_34885":27
   }
}
```

I'm struggling to get the sku of the 2 combinations because the PD_XXXXX is always different so I'm struggling to scrape into that child objects and get the sku dynamically. The same issue will potentially happen with the stocks.

I need a loop on the combinations because in the end, I should add each variant sku and stock to an array.

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there expected output?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I do not have permission to edit my questions.
I need to output
['ABC456BLACK', 49], ['ABC456WHITE', 27]

Comment: Maybe a typo in your Json, but do you want to pair `PD_34874` to `WH32_34884`? Shouldn't it be  `PD_34884`?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yes you are right! Typo mistake.
I need to save that into an array.

Comment: @AndrejKesely please note that the script may encounter more than 1 variation. We need to check the length of data['combinations'] and maybe do a while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine your `combinations` with `stocks`, you can use this example (`d` is your data from the question):

```
out = []
for c in d['combinations']:
    n = c.split('_')[-1]
    out.append([d['combinations'][c]['sku'], d['stocks']['WH32_{}'.format(n)]])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[['ABC456BLACK', 49], ['ABC456WHITE', 27]]
```

Answer (score 2):

see below - I think this is what you are looking for

```
data =  {
   "id":434,
   "sku":"",
   "name":"Product XYZ",
   "brandName":"MyBrand",
   "definition":{
      "basePrice":40,
      "price":29,
   },
   "combinations":{
      "PD_34874":{
         "id":60883,
         "sku":"ABC456BLACK",
      },
      "PD_34885":{
         "id":60884,
         "sku":"ABC456WHITE",
      }
   },
   "stocks":{
      "WH32_34884":49,
      "WH32_34885":27
   }
}
    
skus_n_stocks = [[x[0],x[1]] for x in list(zip([x['sku'] for x in data['combinations'].values()],data['stocks'].values()))]

print(skus_n_stocks)
```

output

```
[['ABC456BLACK', 49], ['ABC456WHITE', 27]]
```

Comment: I need to output 
['ABC456BLACK', 49], ['ABC456WHITE', 27]

Comment: It's almost there. I need to save it to an array, so I need this output:  ['ABC456BLACK', 49], ['ABC456WHITE', 27] .
Also, there was a typo mistake: The "PD_XXXX" number should match the "WH32_XXXX" number.
So, for the variation 1, we have PD_34874 and WH_34874

Comment: so the required output is list of lists: `[ ['ABC456BLACK', 49],['ABC456WHITE', 27]]` ?

Comment: correct. Sorry my question wasn't very clear. It's a shame I do not have permission to edit it.

Comment: check again please.

Comment: Better, but using x[0] and x[1] won't be dynamic enough. The script may encounter more than 1 variation.
We need to check the length of data['combinations'] and maybe do a while loop. 
Note: this script will scrape many pages and each page it scrapes adds the product array to the array list.

Comment: @faia20 I think you can take it from here.. good luck.

Comment: Yes, I believe I can use some knowledge I got from your answer